# How to detect a rollback in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect an occurrence of rollback in a MySQL stored procedure so I could handle the situation accordingly from a PHP script, but so far I can not find any solution.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
     delimiter |
      create procedure multi_inserts(
      IN var1 int(11),
           .
           .
           .
      IN string1 text
      )
      BEGIN

      declare exit handler for sqlexception rollback;
      declare exit handler for sqlwarning rollback;

      START TRANSACTION;
      insert into table1(a,b,c,d) values(var1,var2,var3,var4);
      insert into table2(e,f,g) values(var5,var6,string1);
      COMMIT;

      END
      delimiter ;
```

I did a rollback test on this procedure and it did rollback but I got no false.
I want my stored procedure to throw some kind of error message if the transaction failed, so I could handle it like this:

```
    $result = mysql_query($procedure); 
    if(!$result) 
    {
      //rollback occured do something   
    }
```

Is there a way to detect rollback in MySQL?
Am I missing something?
Any reply will be appreciated. 
Thanks for reading.

---

**Thanks to your advices I fixed this problem. Here's what I did:**

Stored Procedure

```
     delimiter |
      create procedure multi_inserts(
      IN var1 int(11),
           .
           .
           .
      IN string1 text
      )
      BEGIN

      declare exit handler for sqlexception sqlwarning
      BEGIN
      rollback;
      select -1;
      END;

      START TRANSACTION;
      insert into table1(a,b,c,d) values(var1,var2,var3,var4);
      insert into table2(e,f,g) values(var5,var6,string1);
      COMMIT;

      END
      delimiter ;
```

If I use out variable instead of select -1, it gives me this error:

> OUT or INOUT argument is not a
>   variable or NEW pseudo-variable in
>   BEFORE trigger

I don't know what did I wrong, but I couldn't fix this problem.

PHP script

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$procedure);
if(is_object($result))
{
//rollback happened do something!
}
```

If the SP is successful it throws true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an output param and then set it to the value you want in your exit handlers.

Here's an example using your proc:

```
delimiter $$
  create procedure multi_inserts(
  IN var1 int(11),
       .
       .
       .
  IN string1 text,
  OUT p_return_code tinyint unsigned
  )
  BEGIN

  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
    -- ERROR
    set p_return_code = 1;
    rollback;
  END;

  DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
  BEGIN
    -- WARNING
    set p_return_code = 2;
    rollback;
  END;

  START TRANSACTION;
  insert into table1(a,b,c,d) values(var1,var2,var3,var4);
  insert into table2(e,f,g) values(var5,var6,string1);
  COMMIT;

  -- SUCCESS
  set p_return_code = 0;

  END $$
  delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I rewrote my SP and it worked fine in MySQL console but php's mysql_query couldn't handle the result set and gave me funny error, so I updated PHP to 5.3.3 for mysqli_query. I thought this would solve it. How naive of me. After the update I got another error in Pear Auth.php which I'm using as an authentication and I cant see if mysqli_query really would solve the problem unless I solve the new problem first. The latest problem is that I cant update pear auth for some reason. I guess pear auth is incompatible with 5.3.3. Now what should I do? sorry I'm ranting..

Answer (score 1):

You would usually do this PHP-side if you wanted to catch errors. Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I should use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Hey do one thing, use OUTPUT variable and return 1 or 0 as result form SP and do what ever you want on this flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
    $user='root';
    $pass='';
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass, 
      array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  echo "Connected\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
}

try {  
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  $dbh->exec("insert into staff (id, first, last) values (23, 'Joe', 'Bloggs')");
  $dbh->exec("insert into salarychange (id, amount, changedate) 
      values (23, 50000, NOW())");
  $dbh->commit();

} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: please add description