# Mysql nested transaction with rollback

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me if it is possible to call another procedure from within a procedure and if any part of either procedure fails, roll everything back?

If this is possible, can someone please show me a tiny example of how this would be implemented?

**EDIT:** Procedure "b" fails but procedure "a" still inserts a row into table "a". It's my understanding that if any part of the insert fails that everything (both inserts) is rolled back which is not happening here. The questions is why not?

**Procedure "a"**

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;

  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO a(a)
    VALUES(iA);

     CALL b(iB,LAST_INSERT_ID(),@b);
     SELECT @b INTO b;

     IF b !=1 THEN
        ROLLBACK;
      ELSE
        COMMIT;
  END IF;
END
```

**Procedure "b"**

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;

  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO b VALUES(iB,id);
    SET b=1;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle transactions in both procedures, but the proc that is calling the other, should check for the return value and rollback it's transactions based on that. Here is an example of the inner proc:

[How to detect a rollback in MySQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076566/how-to-detect-a-rollback-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

you would then check for `p_return_code` and do a rollback of the parent transaction.

> EDIT:

What I think is happening is that inner SP COMMIT or ROLLBACK affect outer SP TRANSACTION. This code works for me, if inner SP fail it rolls back both insert statements. First call to ab() works, new user record gets inserted and new game record gets inserted, if we remove record from the games table and run ab() again, because user id already exists it rolls back games table insert:

```
create procedure ab()
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO games (title) VALUES ('bad game');
    CALL ba(@ret);
    IF @ret!=0 THEN
      ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;


create procedure ba(OUT return_value tinyint unsigned)
BEGIN
  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
    set return_value = 1;
  END;

  INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES(1);
  set return_value = 0;
END;
```

To test use `call ab();`

Comment: iouri, This unfortunately doesn't work. The first insert is never rolled back when the second procedure fails. I even went as far as using the out value from the second procedure to test with in the first procedure and tried to rollback based on that. Nothing I try works. The insert of the first procedure always occurs.

Comment: Is the insert in the first procedure within START TRANSACTION; statement?

Comment: iouri, would you have any idea why I cannot rollback the first procedure when the second fails? Do I need a savepoint?

Comment: Sure iouri. I'll post up top. Thank you for having a look at this for me.

Comment: Hi iouri, thank you for the sample. Last night, I came up with the same theory about the inner proc committing the outer. I was also able to get it to work when I removed the transaction from the inner proc. Because the inner proc may be called on its own at times, I'd like to keep its transaction if at all possible. Do you know if there is a way to do this and yet use it as an inner proc?

Comment: maybe a conditional boolean parameter to either start or not its own transaction? You can always create another procedure and call that one by itself.