# Will errors handled in sub mysql transactions trigger rollbacks in the mysql transaction that calls it

Tags: mysql, transactions

Assume I have a procedure called prodInner that has an error handler like so

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

and an outer prod called prodOuter with the same error handler. Say there's an issue when running the inner handler and the sqlexception catches it. Will the outer procedure also "fail" and rollback any and all changes (in addition to changes made in other procedure calls)?

Edit

```
    DROP PROCEDURE TEST_INNER;
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_INNER()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            RESIGNAL;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,0);
        INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(1); # throws an error because two values are required
    COMMIT;
end;

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_OUTER()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            RESIGNAL;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (-1,0);
        CALL TEST_INNER();
    COMMIT;
end;

CALL TEST_OUTER()
CALL TEST_INNER()
```

Edit 2, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827036/mysql-nested-transaction-with-rollback) the best solution?

Comment: Read about RESIGNAL statement.

Comment: @Akina the edited sql transaction above does not commit the TEST_INNER but TEST_OUTER fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)

> ***Transaction-control and locking statements.*** BEGIN, LOCK TABLES, SET autocommit = 1 (if the value is not already 1), **START TRANSACTION**, UNLOCK TABLES.

You may investigate this in details: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76bc26fa4e96b5ea3643aabe8161feea

Comment: Since stored procedures have BEGIN and END, is it therefore impossible for an outer procedure to call an inner procedure and stay transacted?

Comment: Edit, perhaps just no inner transaction huh?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the issue but my understanding is very minimal. When the outer procedure is called, a transaction is created. The commit in the inner-procedure however will commit any and all changes in the inner procedure even if the changes in the inner procedure gets rolled back.